# flutter: Getting width and height of video using

Tags: video, ffmpeg, flutter

I am trying to retrieve the width and height of a video using flutter. I have tried using ffmpeg

```
_flutterFFmpeg.getMediaInformation(file.path);
```

but the width and height are occasionally flipped. I have noticed
"rotate" -> "90" and "displaymatrix" -> "rotation of -90.00 degrees" are present in the meta data returned.

Is there a bug free method of using the rotate/display matrix to determine the true width/height of the video or is there a better method/library that can help me here?

Thanks.